# Formatting database results to be consumed as multiple tables by the view

Tags: php, laravel

In the code below, $rows is the result of database query. In the view that consumes this, I need to break the results into a separate table for each vendor.

The below creates a structure that allows this in the template, but it seems like a clunky way of doing it. Advice on how to improve it?

```
    $byVendor = [];
    if (sizeof($rows) < 1)
        return $byVendor;
    $vendor   = $rows[0]->AMVEND;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($rows as $row ) {
        $currentVendor = $row->AMVEND;
        if ($currentVendor != $vendor)
            $i++;
        $byVendor[$i][] = $row;
    }
    return $byVendor;
```

Code used in the view:

```
@section('content')
@foreach($vendors as $vendor)
<table class="table">
    <caption>{{$vendor[0]->AMNAME}}</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
            <th>PO Number</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
    @foreach($vendor as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$item->CREATED_AT}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->SOURCE}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->ITEM}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->QTY}}</td>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We're glad that you found this site to help you improve your code. I hope you get some good reviews!

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `group by` clause to your query on the `AMVEND` column, you won't have to do any looping before you pass the data to the view. You can simply detect when the vendor changes in the view's `foreach` loop.